# How to add my theme's style to woocommerce blocks?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, block-editor

I have found plenty of articles on how to remove the styling from the Woocommerce blocks, but I can find nothing about how to actually use your theme's styling to replace the removed styling from the woocommerce blocks.

Basically I'm using a product tag woocommerce block but it is using the native styling from woocommerce in regards to the button styling and title in each of the cards within the block.

I have removed the styling with this block of code.

```
function cc_deregister_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'cc_deregister_styles', 100 );
```

My question is, what do I do to get my styling added in? When I look at the page there is practically zero styling to the cards within the product tag block now. It's a bunch of li items with their bullet point and not aligned.

I tried doing something like this, but it didn't work.

```
function cc_deregister_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .     '/style.css');
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'cc_deregister_styles', 100 );
```

So what do I do to add my theme back in?

Comment: I'm not clear what you expect to be able to add "back in". The product cards aren't styled because you removed the styles. If you want them to appear styled you need to add CSS styling them to your stylesheet. If your theme had its own styles for those blocks then it would already be applied.

Comment: If I use the product tag shortcode I'm able to bring in a specific brand of product to my product page. Each of the products that would display on this page are going to show a specific font format, style to the button and some custom padding/margin.

Now when I go and use the woocommerce blocks, it's using the default styling of woocommerce, I'd like it to use the styling I had it using with the shortcode, but for some reason when I remove the styling it gets rid of it all. That is why I was thinking I need to enqueue my styling back into the blocks?

Comment: The WooCommerce blocks probably use different markup to the old shortcodes. I wouldn’t necessarily expect them to look the same. But since third party plugins are off topic here that’s something you’d need to ask the WooCommerce developers, or the developers of your theme.

Comment: Gotcha okay, I was going through WooCommerce's documentation and it was saying to use the blocks over shortcode now to future proof the site which is why I made the switch. I'll reach out to WooCommerce's forum, thanks.